# aspose nested tables

Tags: c#, nested, rendering, aspose

Doing research for [ASPOSE.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx). Everything works fine just last thing remains. Question is how to render table inside table? In the [Nested table](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Create+Nested+Table) documentation sample data is tightly coupled with presentation layer. I need separation of data and presentation layer. So little test here:

```
[Test]
public void CreateDocumentRecurentalTableInTableTest()
{
  // Structural items are in [], values/data in {}
  //GIVEN (presentation layer)
  const string FileName = "_6CreateDocumentRecurentalTableInTableTest.txt";
  var doc = new Document();
  var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
  builder.Writeln("TEST -- START");

  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableStart:[MyTable] MERGEFORMAT");

  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [MyTableCol1] \* MERGEFORMAT");
  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [MyTableCol2] \* MERGEFORMAT");

  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableStart:[SubTable] MERGEFORMAT");

  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [SubTable.Col1] \* MERGEFORMAT");
  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [SubTable.Col2] \* MERGEFORMAT");

  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableEnd:[SubTable] MERGEFORMAT");
  builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableEnd:[MyTable] MERGEFORMAT");

  builder.Writeln("\nTEST -- END");

  //WHEN (Data layer)
  using (var dt2 = new DataTable("[SubTable]"))
  {
      dt2.Columns.Add("[SubTable.Col1]");
      dt2.Columns.Add("[SubTable.Col2]");

      dt2.Rows.Add(" {SubTable.Row1.Cont1} ", " {SubTable.Row1.Cont2} ");
      dt2.Rows.Add(" {SubTable.Row2.Cont1} ", " {SubTable.Row2.Cont2} ");
      dt2.Rows.Add(" {SubTable.Row3.Cont1} ", " {SubTable.Row3.Cont2} ");

      using (var dt = new DataTable("[MyTable]"))
      {
          dt.Columns.Add("[MyTableCol1]");
          dt.Columns.Add("[MyTableCol2]");

          dt.Rows.Add(" {MyTable.firstRow} ", dt2);

          doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dt);
          doc.Save(FileName, SaveFormat.Text);
      }
  }

  //THEN
  //Assert...
}
```

Getting result:

```
TEST -- START
{MyTable.firstRow} [SubTable]«TableStart:[SubTable]»«[SubTable.Col1]»«[SubTable.Col2]»«TableEnd:[SubTable]»
TEST -- END
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
TEST -- START
 {MyTable.firstRow}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont2} 
                     {SubTable.Row2.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row2.Cont2} 
                     {SubTable.Row3.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row3.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.nextRow}  
TEST -- END
```

If both tables are stored in DataSet.Tables then it renders mutiple times per each table:

```
TEST -- START
 {MyTable.firstRow}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.firstRow}  {SubTable.Row2.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row2.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.firstRow}  {SubTable.Row3.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row3.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.nextRow}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.nextRow}  {SubTable.Row2.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row2.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.nextRow}  {SubTable.Row3.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row3.Cont2} 
TEST -- END
```

Answer (score 2):

Perform required re-factoring to both the presentation layer and data layer codes as follows:

```
public void CreateDocumentRecurentalTableInTableTest()
{

// Structural items are in [], values/data in {}
//GIVEN (presentation layer)
//const string FileName = "_6CreateDocumentRecurentalTableInTableTest.txt";

var doc = new Document();
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.Writeln("TEST -- START");
builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableStart:[MyTable] MERGEFORMAT");
builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [MyTableCol1] \* MERGEFORMAT");
builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [MyTableCol2] \* MERGEFORMAT");
builder.Writeln();

builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableStart:[SubTable] MERGEFORMAT");
builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [SubTable.Col1] \* MERGEFORMAT");
builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD [SubTable.Col2] \* MERGEFORMAT");
builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableEnd:[SubTable] MERGEFORMAT");
builder.Writeln();

builder.InsertField(@"MERGEFIELD TableEnd:[MyTable] MERGEFORMAT");

builder.Writeln("\nTEST -- END");

//WHEN (Data layer)
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

var dt = new DataTable("[MyTable]");
dt.Columns.Add("[MyTableCol1]");
dt.Columns.Add("[MyTableCol2]");
dt.Columns.Add("[Id]");

dt.Rows.Add(" {MyTable.firstRow} ", "", 0);
dt.Rows.Add(" {MyTable.nextRow} ", "", 1);

var dt2 = new DataTable("[SubTable]");
dt2.Columns.Add("[SubTable.Col1]");
dt2.Columns.Add("[SubTable.Col2]");
dt2.Columns.Add("[Id]");

dt2.Rows.Add(" {SubTable.Row1.Cont1} ", " {SubTable.Row1.Cont2} ", 0);
dt2.Rows.Add(" {SubTable.Row2.Cont1} ", " {SubTable.Row2.Cont2} ", 0);
dt2.Rows.Add(" {SubTable.Row3.Cont1} ", " {SubTable.Row3.Cont2} ", 0);

ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

ds.Relations.Add("MyRelation", dt.Columns[2], dt2.Columns[2], true);

doc.MailMerge.CleanupOptions = MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedRegions | MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs;

doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(ds);

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\\out.docx");

//THEN

//Assert...
}
```

This gives the exact same output as you desired, that is like:

```
TEST -- START
 {MyTable.firstRow} 
  {SubTable.Row1.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row1.Cont2} 
  {SubTable.Row2.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row2.Cont2} 
  {SubTable.Row3.Cont1}  {SubTable.Row3.Cont2} 
 {MyTable.nextRow} 
TEST -- END
```

My name is Iqbal and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

In short: data tables must be linked (like RDBMS).

In brief: [Read more here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Set+up+Relations+for+use+in+Nested+Mail+Merge+with+Regions).