# Aspose.Words for .Net insert a table into a table cell

Tags: c#, embed, aspose.words

I have a C# .Net Windows app.  We are using Aspose.Words to generate a document from our data.  Insied this document is a main table containg several rows.  We have a requirement to insert another table inside one of the cells on the main table.  I'm not seeing how to do that.  I have looked for InsertTable(), tried appending the table to be insertted as a Table Node.  I've tried using the document builder to MoveTo() the cell where I want to put the table.  So far no dice.  Ideas?

EDIT:  the Table objects being used are Aspose.Words.Tables.Table objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aspose nested tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15222963/2596334).

Comment: @Okuma...I don't think this is a duplicate. I am using the Aspose.Words.Tables.Table object not DataSet objects. I don't see a Relation object on the Aspose Table.  Thanks for the suggestion, tho

Answer (score 3):

Try the below example, it worked with the latest release at my end.
The first table is created in document.
Second table is created inside the cell of first table.

```
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document();
// Create first table with 1 row and 2 columns
Aspose.Words.Tables.Table table = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Table(doc);
// Add the table to the document.
doc.FirstSection.Body.AppendChild(table);
Aspose.Words.Tables.Row row = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Row(doc);
table.AppendChild(row);
Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell cell1 = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell(doc);
row.AppendChild(cell1);
Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell cell2 = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell(doc);
row.AppendChild(cell2);
table.SetBorders(LineStyle.Dot, 1, System.Drawing.Color.Red);

// Add the second table in cell1
Aspose.Words.Tables.Table table2 = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Table(doc);
cell1.AppendChild(table2);
Aspose.Words.Tables.Row row2 = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Row(doc);
table2.AppendChild(row2);
Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell cell3 = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell(doc);
row2.AppendChild(cell3);
Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell cell4 = new Aspose.Words.Tables.Cell(doc);
row2.AppendChild(cell4);
table2.SetBorders(LineStyle.DotDash, 1, System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
```

Output document looks like
[image: output document]